# Determine enabled input method

Tags: android, input, keyboard

On Android, I want to check programmatically if the InputMethod provided by my application is the **current activated input method**, or not.

Currently, I use a trick : detect whether my InputMethodService is started or not.

```
public boolean isInputMethodEnabled() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager).getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningServiceInfo> servicesInfo = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (RunningServiceInfo serviceInfo : servicesInfo) {
        if (MyInputMethodService.class.getName().equals(serviceInfo.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works well in general, but fails when the app is updated : my input method is still selected, but the service is not started yet. The service will be started when a keyboard is required for the first time, and until then **isInputMethodEnabled()** will return false.

So **my question** is : do you know another way to check if my input method is selected, or do you know a way to restart the input method service after an update, without having to show a textview ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer on another Stack Overflow question :

[Android: Determine active input method from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380234/android-determine-active-input-method-from-code)

The following code (**updated**) did the trick :

```
public boolean isInputMethodEnabled() {
    String id = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);

    ComponentName defaultInputMethod = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(id);

    ComponentName myInputMethod = new ComponentName(mContext, MyInputMethodService.class);

    return myInputMethod.equals(defaultInputMethod);
}
```

Comment: This is terribly fragile: return "my.package/.MyInputMethodService".equals(id).  Use ComponentName to parse the value of DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD, and compare that against an appropriately initialized ComponentName for your service.

Comment: **or do you know a way to restart the input method service after an update, without having to show a textview ?** Hey @piwai, You mention this in your question.Do you get the solution of this stuff? I want to know  how to restart the input method service, but not get success :( can you help?

Comment: @Yog Guru: did you try to kill the process?