# Open settings screen to activate input method

Tags: android, input

I have written a custom input method (soft keyboard). I can check whether it's enabled or not based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723339/292233). Now if it's enabled (but not the current IME) I can call `imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();` which displays a list of enabled IMEs so the user can pick mine.

However, if my IME is not enabled in the system settings, I would rather take the user directly to the system settnigs screen so he can enable my IME (I remember that Swiftkey does this after installing).

How can I open this specific settings screen?

Comment: You can open the Android settings                                                 

import android.provider.Settings;
ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS));

Comment: that's easy! thank you! (you can make this an answer if you want)

Comment: Please accept, If this may help you.

Comment: It should help others to easily find the answer. Note that I used the correct settings now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can open the Android settings. Use below code

```
import android.provider.Settings; 
ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS));
```