# How to get current InputMethodService

Tags: android, ime

How can I get the InputMethodService of the default InputMethod?

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380234/android-determine-active-input-method-from-code) but I don't know how to get the InputMethodService by an InputMethodInfo:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
List<InputMethodInfo> mInputMethodProperties = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();

final int N = mInputMethodProperties.size();

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    InputMethodInfo imi = mInputMethodProperties.get(i);

    if (imi.getId().equals(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD))) {

        //imi contains the information about the keyboard you are using
        break;
    }
}
```

Are there any other solutions I overlooked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by saying "get" you mean get it's id, and you want to know the id of the currently selected (chosen as default) here is the way:

```
    String currentKeyboard =  Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "get" the `InputMethodService`, as it is running in a different process than yours.

Comment: Some methods of InputMethodManager were deprecated (e.g. hideSoftInputFromInputMethod). According to the documentation we should use methods of InputMethodService. So, I suppose that there is a way to get it

Comment: @Vaios It could be that you're only supposed to call these methods using `this.` when you extend `InputMethodService` (eg creating a custom system keyboard).