# Is there any way to detect the type of softInput Keyboard visible

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I had 6 `EditText` in a row to enter mac address, so after validating the user input in the macAddress `EditText`, if the no. of entries in one `EditText` becomes 2, i would call the focus on next edit box, as shown below.

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        //myMacArray is an array for storing macaddress editTexts ID
        //mIndex represents the the index for for each EditText
        if((myMacArray [mIndex]).getText().length() == 2)
            if(mIndex < 5)
                myMacArray [mIndex+1].requestFocus();//requesting focus to 
                                                     //next editText
    }
```

Now, if i the user is using the soft Qwerty keypad then its working fine....but in case of 3X4 keypad if the user wants to enter "1b"(inputing "b" in 3x4 keypad will require to press the 2nd button twice) in any macAddress' editText , it wont work as the focus is now shifted to next editBox just after the first user click.

Please let me know if there is a way to detect the type of keypad opened by user or some other way to deal with this

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5723339/4385913) is what you looking for?

Comment: @JoanColmenero: sorry but this is not what i am looking for..... this doesnot provide me any way to differentiate between Qwerty keypad and 3x4 kepad. thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can "force" the type of keyboard you want to come up by specifying the

```
android:inputType="<...>"
```

attribute in your edittext. If your users are going to be typing letters and numbers there is no reason to let them use a phone pad.

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType