# How can I read out and set the "shift state" of the soft keyboard on Android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText view, and the app user can type in any text (e.g. username or password). The user might switch to the "numeric shift state" on the soft keyboard, e.g. when only entering number digits. When the user next enters the activity I'd like to restore the "numeric shift state" of the soft keyboard, so that he doesn't always have to switch to the keyboard state he last used.

So I need to "read out" somehow what state of the input method is currently active when I leave the activity (or the focus of the field). I also have to initialize the input method of the field when opening the soft keyboard. Is there a way to do it on android?

Note: I don't want to force input method by setting inputMethod to "number".

Comment: Do you see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/5723339/1697047 ?

Comment: I saw the post, and tried out the code, but it doesn't get you the "shift states", only the installed "keyboards" (samsung keypad, swype, mymobiler,. etc). I'm afraid Gabe Sechan is right that there's no way to find this out...

Comment: yes he is right, there is no direct way or concepts  to find that.You can try some thing new. Dot give up. You can find a solution, all the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such API.  No such concepts even-  the idea of a "shift state" may exist in an individual keyboard, but its not part of the Android framework and may or may not exist within a given keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In fact some keyboard could use meta-states, by doing this 'shift' work by sending keycode_shift to android system. But it's not an forced behavior so we can't detect what's real current status is.