# Best way to detect editText inputType in Android?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I developed a simple keyboard.

It's a T9 keyboard that is conceived specifically for phones with an hardware keyboard.

When I want to write something into a standard EditText I have no problem, but when i try to write numbers inside an ediText with `android:inputType="phone"` or `android:inputType="number"` the keyboard still tries to write letters.

My question is: What is the best and simplest way to detect if the editText I have focus on is Number-only, Text-only, etc. from my custom Keyboard?
How can I detect the inputType from my Keyboard?

I hope someone of you already solved this problem in the past and can help...thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if(txt.getInputType()==InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE){
//do something
}
```

Also check this question: [Android: Determine active input method from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380234/android-determine-active-input-method-from-code) it describes using the **InputMethodManager**

**

**Another Approach:**

**

when developing your custom keyboard: as described here  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html#IMEUI

you extends **InputMethodService** which provides the method **onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting)**

onStartInputView has the EditorInfo argument which has the [inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#inputType) field that you can know the current edit text input type from

Comment: The Keyboard is a service, has no Views in it (except for the soft-keyboard Layout) and it interfaces with third-paty apps. So I cannot call `txt.getInputType()`...I was thinking to override a method that gets EditorInfo or a textView...any suggestions?

Comment: In the example you suggested me there is a `String id` set to `Settings.Secure.getString(
   getContentResolver(), 
   Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD
);`, what does this method return?

Comment: Thank you @Mina Samy, you gave me a lot of infos!

Answer (score 1):

Under "**Handling different input types**" on [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html):

> When an input field receives focus and your IME starts, the system calls `onStartInputView()`, passing in an `EditorInfo` object that contains details about the input type and other attributes of the text field. In this object, the `inputType` field contains the text field's input type.

It then goes on to explain how to read the input type and what many input types (and their related flags) mean.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Inside onStartInputView() I set X= true if inputType & InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE condition is true...but no luck...have you a sample code? Maybe I'm missing something really silly..

Comment: @Ben At present your question clearly asks how to tell the input type of the view, and this is the mechanism for that. If that isn't the problem you're having, then you should update your question and include some code.

Comment: Sorry @Karakuri, I'm on train right now, usually I post all the code. Tomorrow I'll be able to edit my Question, but I think you helped me a lot confirming I'm on the right way.