# How to get all enabled keyboard in xamarin.forms with C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, keyboard

Good day,

in android phone -> virtual keyboard, system list all the enabled keyboards in this page, how can i get all enabled keyboards type with C# in my Xamarin.forms APP?

Thanks!
Roll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, you could use `InputDevice`.

`InputDevice`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/InputDevice

You could try the code below:

```
int[] devicesIds = InputDevice.GetDeviceIds();
        foreach (var item in devicesIds)
        {
            //Check the device you want
            InputDevice device = InputDevice.GetDevice(item);
            //device.getName must to have virtual
            var s = device.Name;
            var b = device.KeyboardType;
        }
```

You could use `DependencyService` to call this in Xamarin.Forms.

`DependencyService`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Answer (score 0):

thanks your reply, i try the way you suggested, but the returned value was not  i want...

i found another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380234/android-determine-active-input-method-from-code), use that way and finally get the things i want,

here is my code to share:

```
InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        IList<InputMethodInfo> mInputMethodProperties = manager.EnabledInputMethodList;

        IEnumerator<InputMethodInfo> imi = mInputMethodProperties.GetEnumerator();

        while (imi.MoveNext())
        {
            InputMethodInfo inputInfo = imi.Current;

            var iN = inputInfo.ServiceName;
        }
```

Best Regards & thanks

Roll